# Checking SIM is inserted or not in the GSMCOMM modem

Tags: c#, gsm

I am using `GSMCOMM` http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htmlibrary in C# to send and receive SMS.

So I need check Sim is inserted or not in the modem.

Is there any way to check this in C# ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to read the IMSI number with the AT command line `AT+CMEE=1; +CIMI`, that should give you `+CME ERROR: 10` (SIM not inserted) if there is no sim card.

See [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) for more details on the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Windows Mobile Broadband API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (supported from Windows 7 onwards).
For example if you get the connection state using IMbnConnection::GetConnectionState, and there is no SIM inserted, you will get E_MBN_SIM_NOT_INSERTED as the return value.